# While loop condition in calculating square root using Newton-Raphson method

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm currently taking a course where the instructor used the following code to implement the square root functionality in Java -

```
public class Sqrt { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        // read in the command-line argument
        double c = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
        double epsilon = 1.0e-15;  // relative error tolerance
        double t = c;              // estimate of the square root of c

        // repeatedly apply Newton update step until desired precision is achieved
        while (Math.abs(t - c/t) > epsilon*t) {
            t = (c/t + t) / 2.0;
        }

        // print out the estimate of the square root of c
        System.out.println(t);
    }

}
```

However, if I slightly change the while loop condition to `while (Math.abs(t - (c / t)) >= epsilon)` instead of `while (Math.abs(t - (c / t)) >= t * epsilon)`, the program gets stuck on an infinite loop for some inputs like 234.0.

I used the Eclipse debugger and found that my code after a certain point returns a value of t that is close to the square root of 234, but still greater than EPSILON. And using the update formula, yields the same value of t after every iteration, hence the loop gets stuck there forever.

Can someone explain as to why the program fails when using `>= EPSILON` but works perfectly fine when using `>= t * EPSILON`? As per my understanding, given the extremely small value of EPSILON, t * EPSILON shouldn't eventually be too different than EPSILON, yet the difference is huge when implemented in the program.

Comment: Using `=` with `double` (or any kind of `float` for that matter) is fraught with dangers because some floating-point numbers can be equal unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`double` has around 15 digits of precision (or 1 to 2^52 or 4.5e15). When you calculate `t * epsilon` you around requiring an error of 1 to `1e15/234` ratio which is possible with `double`, when you use `epsilon` you are requiring a ratio of 1 to `1e15` which is at the limits of the precision of double unless it's an exact value and the error is `0`. e.g. try this for `256` and it might work, but anything which is not an exactly value probably doesn't.

A simple solution to an arbitrary end point is to stop once the error doesn't improve from one iteration to the next. This is will give you the most accurate solution using this formula possible.

Comment: Could you clarify as to how those ratios or the digits of precision were obtained? I mean I don't get how you obtained those ratios `1 to 1e15` or `1 to 254e15`.

Comment: You specify epsilon = 1e-15 so the difference between the `t` and `c / t` can be `t * epsilon` what has a ratio of `(t - c/t) / (t * epsilon)` or 1e15 but without `t` `(t - c/t) / epsilon` has a ratio of 1e15/234 which is a smaller ratio.

Comment: This explanation completely makes sense. The issue indeed was getting to the limits of Double precision. I can use the previous code (for the input of 234) by changing `eps` to `1e-14`, but of course as the input number gets larger, the `eps` needs to be modified again. So, using `t * epsilon` is indeed a clever way to keep a good check.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use a debugger to see how the numbers progress and why for example the square root of 234 causes an unending loop when `epsilon` is not multiplied by `t`.

I have used IntelliJ with a logging breakpoint to see how the numbers progress and why the unending loop happens:

[image]

First I have used this expression in the logging breakpoint:

```
" " + Math.abs(t - c/t) + " " + epsilon
```

for this code:

```
private static void calcRoot(String arg) {
    // read in the command-line argument
    double c = Double.parseDouble(arg);
    double epsilon = 1.0e-15;  // relative error tolerance
    double t = c;              // estimate of the square root of c

    // repeatedly apply Newton update step until desired precision is achieved
    while (Math.abs(t - c/t) > epsilon ) {
        t = (c/t + t) / 2.0;
    }

    // print out the estimate of the square root of c
    System.out.println(t);
}
```

and this is the result proving that actually `epsilon` is smaller than `Math.abs(t - c/t)` and this `Math.abs(t - c/t)` stops in its progression:

```
 233.0 1.0E-15
 115.50851063829788 1.0E-15
 55.82914775415816 1.0E-15
 24.47988606961853 1.0E-15
 7.647106514310517 1.0E-15
 0.927185521197492 1.0E-15
 0.014043197832668497 1.0E-15
 3.2230278765865705E-6 1.0E-15
 1.723066134218243E-13 1.0E-15
 1.7763568394002505E-15 1.0E-15
 1.7763568394002505E-15 1.0E-15
 1.7763568394002505E-15 1.0E-15
 1.7763568394002505E-15 1.0E-15
 1.7763568394002505E-15 1.0E-15
 1.7763568394002505E-15 1.0E-15
 1.7763568394002505E-15 1.0E-15
 ...
```

If I then use `epsilon * t` I and update the logging expression to `" " + Math.abs(t - c/t) + " " + epsilon * t` I can see a totally different console output:

```
 233.0 2.34E-13
 115.50851063829788 1.175E-13
 55.82914775415816 5.974574468085106E-14
 24.47988606961853 3.1831170803771985E-14
 7.647106514310517 1.959122776896272E-14
 0.927185521197492 1.5767674511807463E-14
 0.014043197832668497 1.5304081751208715E-14
 3.2230278765865705E-6 1.529706015229238E-14
 1.723066134218243E-13 1.5297058540778443E-14
```

**Update**

If you try the same thing with the `BigDecimal` class, you will be able to calculate the square root of `234` in case you choose enough rounding digits (see the `scale` variable below):

```
private static void calcRootBig(String arg) {
    // read in the command-line argument
    BigDecimal c = new BigDecimal(arg);
    BigDecimal epsilon = new BigDecimal(1.0e-15);  // relative error tolerance
    BigDecimal t = new BigDecimal(c.toString());              // estimate of the square root of c
    BigDecimal two = new BigDecimal("2.0");

    // repeatedly apply Newton update step until desired precision is achieved
    int scale = 10;
    while (t.subtract(c.divide(t, scale, RoundingMode.CEILING)).abs().compareTo(epsilon) > 0) {
        t = c.divide(t, scale, RoundingMode.CEILING).add(t).divide(two, scale, RoundingMode.CEILING);
    }

    // print out the estimate of the square root of c
    System.out.println(t);
}
```

Yet if you choose just 3 for the rounding scale, you will be caught up again in an unending loop.

So it seems that it is the precision of the floating point division which is actually causing the unending loop in your case. The multiplication of `epsilon * t` is just a trick to overcome the lack of rounding precision in the default floating point operations.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. It only shows what I already tried and mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Ratus you are right. Please check my update with the usage of `BigDecimal`.